# async/await not working properly with fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fs

I pass a callback to fs.writeStream, and for some reason any tasks after it are being called first, before the callback is executed.

```
async function writeFile(file, callBack) {
    // awaiting this also doesn't work
  fs.writeFile(arg1, arg2, arg3, (error) => callBack(error)) 

}

async function task() {
  let count = 0;

  const callBack = (error) => {
    if (error) {
      count--;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }

  for(const file of files) { // files.length = 1
    await writeFile(file, callBack);  
  }
  
  console.log(count) // Prints 0, should be 1. Why does this get called before the callback?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are calling it wrong. If you want to wait for an async function you have to call it like this with `await`

```
await yourFunction(...);
```

and not like this with `async`

```
async yourFunction();
```

Second, you are obviously mixing `async` functions and functions with callbacks. Ie, when you have

```
async function yourFunction() {
  anotherFunction((error, data) => { 
     ... 
  });
}
```

you are actually returning a `Promise<void>` which immediately resolves. `async` function do not wait for any callbacks of callback-based functions.

And third, you are not using the `file` parameter of your `writeFile(file, callBack)` function, but three completely undefined arguments `arg1, arg2, arg3`

For your current problem, there are two possibilities

1. You import the promise functions of the `fs` module and use them properly (available since Node v10)

   ```
    const fsp = require("fs").promises;

    async function writeFile(filename, data, errorHandler) {
      try{
        await fsp.writeFile(filename, data);
      } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(e);
      }
    }
   ```
2. You import the classic callback-form of the fs module and wrap the functions into a promise

   ```
    const fs = require("fs");

    async function writeFile(filename, data, errorHandler) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(filename, data, (e) => {
          if (e) {
            errorHandler(e);
            // if you want to continue and adjust the count 
            // even if the writeFile failed
            // you don't need the reject here
            return reject(e);
          }
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }
   ```

Comment: `async` was a typo while posting this - should be `await`. I also tried awaiting `fs.writeFile` but didn't work. Will try out your suggestions!

Comment: what "didn't work" with `await fs.writeFile`?  Was there an error message? Did you import the promise-form of the fs-module?

Answer (score 0):

Given you imported the correct fs library, namely `fs/promises`, your answer should look like this:

```js
async function writeFile(file) {
  await fs.writeFile(file);
}

async function task() {
  let count = 0;

  const callBack = (error) => {
    if (error) {
      count--;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }

  for(const file of files) { // files.length = 1
    await writeFile(file);  
  }
  
  console.log(count) // Prints 0, should be 1. Why does this get called before the callback?
}
```

You were missing the required `await` to actually await the asynchronous result of `fsPromises.writeFile` as you can see here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options
Also if you're using the promise based fs you will not have nor need the callback (ftfy)

If you still want to count, do it like this:

```js
async function writeFile(file) {
  await fs.writeFile(file);
}

async function task() {
  let count = 0;

  for (const file of files) { // files.length = 1
    try {
      await writeFile(file);
      count++; // <-------- NOTICE THIS PART HERE
    } catch (e) {
      count--;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(count) // Prints 0, should be 1. Why does this get called before the callback?
}
```

Comment: rather obsolete, but yes. fixed that. ty